# How can I update substitutions values of google cloud build trigger using bash script?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, substitution, google-cloud-build, build-triggers

I want to write a script where I will pass the values and the script will update all the substitutions values automically. In cloud build trigger, I am passing values like _DOCKER_IMAGE, _IMAGE_TAG, _BUCKET_NAME etc. to the substitutions values of the cloud build trigger. I was looking into the documentation [Gcloud command options for triggers](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/builds/triggers) but did not find any reference to update the substitutions values using gcloud command. I tried these commands but it was failed to execute.

```
gcloud beta builds triggers update <TRIGGER_NAME> --project=$PROJECT_ID --substitutions=_BUCKET_NAME=demo-bucket-name

gcloud alpha builds triggers update <TRIGGER_NAME> --project=$PROJECT_ID --substitutions=_BUCKET_NAME=demo-bucket-name
```

The error message I got:

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.builds.triggers) Invalid choice: 'update'.
> Maybe you meant:
> gcloud beta builds triggers export
> gcloud beta builds connections update github
> gcloud beta builds connections update github-enterprise
> gcloud builds cancel
> gcloud builds describe
> gcloud builds list
> gcloud builds log
> gcloud builds submit

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#:%7E:text=To%20override%20the%20substitution%20value%20you%20specified%20in%20the%20build%20config%20file%2C)

> To override the substitution value you specified in the build config file, use the --substitutions flag in the gcloud builds submit command. Note that substitutions are a mapping of variables to values rather than arrays or sequences. You can override default substitution variable values except for $PROJECT_ID and $BUILD_ID. The following command overrides the default values.

```
gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml \
 --substitutions=_BUCKET_NAME=demo-bucket-name
```

You can also check this documentation on [Updating a build trigger](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers#updating_a_build_trigger) which might help

> Cloud Build trigger automatically starts a build whenever you make any changes to your source code. You can configure the trigger to build your code on any changes to the source repository or only changes that match certain criteria.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but It did not give me the exact answer I want.

Comment: can you please elaborate why it didn't answer your question. did the above documentations not helpful?

Comment: Not actually. I want to use gcloud command to update a substitution value of a trigger. Lets say. trigger name: demo-repo-build, substitution_value= _BUCKET_NAME=demo-bucket
now i want to write a script, to put the command so that it will update the value of the substitution.
Your command will work for one service, but i want command to work for multiple let's say 10+ triggers

Comment: seems it is not possible since the  substitutions are related to a specific build either by being specified in the cloudbuild.yaml config file or in the [--substitutions argument](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit#--substitutions) flag for the gcloud command.

Answer (score 1):

Despite `update` being in the documentation [see here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/builds/triggers/update), it looks like `gcloud builds triggers update` isn't a valid command:

[image]

I did try running `gcloud components update` to see if gcloud was out of date however it didn't seem to make a difference

My only suggestion would be to try a delete then a create:

```
gcloud triggers delete <TRIGGER_NAME>
gcloud beta builds triggers create github \ 
--name=<TRIGGER_NAME> \
<TRIGGER_CONFIG> \
--substitutions=_BUCKET_NAME=demo-bucket-name
```